# How to export Slots in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, altium

I made my first PCB with slots, and Altium is generation two .txt files...one for the drills, and one for the slots...how do I combine them to send it to the manufacture?

Comment: They'll probably want them separated, and if not it's easy for them to combine.  Just note what each file is in a readme when you send it to them.  The slots are done in a different step than the via drilling.

Comment: Humm ok...I just feel unconfortable with so many different ways to interpret a PCB and repesent a slot..and OSH Park dont show them, unless you put it on the board edge layer I think

Answer (score 1):

I send them separately without any other notifications.